# dynamic way to work with checkboxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have alertdialog with custom checkboxes, i need to pass the selected choices to the host activity, and persist the selected choices. here is my code :

```
    public class TimelineSettings extends DialogFragment {
    ArrayList<Integer> selected_categories = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean[] itemsChecked = {false, false, false, false, false, false};
    private FlatCheckBox fourniture,nourriture,voyages,habillement,medias,autres;


    public interface dialoglistener {
        public void onOkay(ArrayList<Integer> selected);
        public void onCancel();
    }
    dialoglistener mlistener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // ensure that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the dialogListener so we can send events to the host
            mlistener = (dialoglistener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // if activity doesn't implement the interface, throw an exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement dialogListener");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View custom = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_settings,null);
        fourniture = (FlatCheckBox)custom.findViewById(R.id.fourniture);
        nourriture = (FlatCheckBox)custom.findViewById(R.id.nourriture);
        voyages = (FlatCheckBox)custom.findViewById(R.id.voyages);
        habillement = (FlatCheckBox)custom.findViewById(R.id.habillement);
        medias = (FlatCheckBox)custom.findViewById(R.id.medias);
        autres = (FlatCheckBox)custom.findViewById(R.id.autres);

        if (selected_categories.contains(0)){
            fourniture.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (selected_categories.contains(1)){
            nourriture.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (selected_categories.contains(2)){
            voyages.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (selected_categories.contains(3)){
            habillement.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (selected_categories.contains(4)){
            medias.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (selected_categories.contains(5)){
            autres.setChecked(true);
        }
               builder.setView(custom)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       checkboxState();
                        mlistener.onOkay(selected_categories);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        mlistener.onCancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
    public void checkboxState(){
        if (fourniture.isChecked()){
            if(!selected_categories.contains(0)){
                selected_categories.add(0);
                itemsChecked[0]=true;
            }
            else if (selected_categories.contains(0)) {
                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                selected_categories.remove(0);
                itemsChecked[0]=false;
            }

        }
        if (nourriture.isChecked()){
            if(!selected_categories.contains(1)){
                selected_categories.add(1);
                itemsChecked[1]=true;
            }
            else if (selected_categories.contains(1)) {
                selected_categories.remove(1);
                itemsChecked[1]=false;
            }

        }

        if (voyages.isChecked()){
            if(!selected_categories.contains(2)){
                selected_categories.add(2);
                itemsChecked[2]=true;
            }
            else if (selected_categories.contains(2)) {
                selected_categories.remove(2);
                itemsChecked[2]=false;
            }

        }
        if (habillement.isChecked()){
            if(!selected_categories.contains(3)){
                selected_categories.add(3);
                itemsChecked[3]=true;
            }
            else if (selected_categories.contains(3)) {
                selected_categories.remove(3);
                itemsChecked[3]=false;
            }

        }

        if (medias.isChecked()){
            if(!selected_categories.contains(4)){
                selected_categories.add(4);
                itemsChecked[4]=true;
            }
            else if (selected_categories.contains(4)) {
                selected_categories.remove(4);
                itemsChecked[4]=false;
            }

        }

        if (autres.isChecked()){
            if(!selected_categories.contains(5)){
                selected_categories.add(5);
                itemsChecked[5]=true;
            }
            else if (selected_categories.contains(5)) {
                selected_categories.remove(5);
                itemsChecked[5]=false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

this code works fine, but it does not look so! too much if elses...
my question is if there is a way to use a loop on my checkboxes to get their state, and then to set the elements of the array `itemschecked` to true/false for the persistency.
thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep an array of FlatCheckBoxs:

```
private FlatCheckBox [] check = new FlatCheckBox[6];
```

and use an enum to retrive what checkbox you need:

```
private enum Names
{
    fourniture(0),
    nourriture(1),
    voyages(2),
    habillement(3),
    medias(4),
    autres(5);

    private int val;

    Names(int a)
    {
        val = a;
    }

    public int get()
    {
        return val;
    }
};
```

Now use:

```
    public void checkboxState()
    {
        for(FlatCheckBox fb : check)
        {
            if (fb.isChecked())
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

And you can access individual elements of the array like this:

```
FlatCheckBox fourniture = check[Names.fourniture.get()];
```

I would use the enum for a better readability, using [0], [1] ... can be confusing and lead to programming errors.

Comment: can you please show me how to use that array to replace                 `if(!selected_categories.contains(0)){
                    selected_categories.add(0);
                    itemsChecked[0]=true;
                }
                else if (selected_categories.contains(0)) {
                    selected_categories.remove(0);
                    itemsChecked[0]=false;
                }` and if i can use it to replace this :         `if (selected_categories.contains(0)){
            fourniture.setChecked(true);`

Comment: 1st, why is needed to have an ArrayList and an array of booleans to keep track of the state of the checkboxes? 1 of the 2 is enough IMO.

Comment: The arraylist is to send the selected items to the host activity, the array of booleans is for keeping track of the state. this might not be the best way to do it ! i'm open to your suggestions :)

Comment: I would keep just an ArrayList of Names for both purposes (you can re-name the enum as you'd like): ArrayList<Names> checked_items = new ArrayList<Names>();
  checked_items.add(Names.fourniture); 
  checked_items.remove(Names.autres); Write the enum in a file of its own to be accessible in all project files.

Comment: that seems to be a good solution(+1) (but it will require some major changes on my project). I need to deliver a working version of the project very soon so i will stick to what i already done and try to use the enums asap. will let you know. thanks